# Sound JS Not running on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, soundjs

I have a player that uses video, photos and sound.

If a video is running, SoundJS works fine on iOS. If there is no video, I can't get SoundJS to run at all on iOS (fine everywhere else).

I'm trying to play a sound on the onTouch event,  and I'm using PreloadJS and a Queue.

While loading I get this error on iOS

```
Uncaught TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this._soundInstances[b].length')
```

I'm loading the soundFile as such

```
    var props = {};
    props.loop = 0;
  taskVoice = new createjs.Sound.play(cdnPrefix + file,props);
```

This was loading first intermittently event without an onTouch event, and is now not loading at all.